# Are soldering fluxes safe to touch?

Tags: pcb, soldering, flux, solder-paste

I'm new to PCB soldering. I just bought a cheap soldering iron, solder wire and flux to try something. I have no previous experience with soldering.

I'm well aware of the potential risks of prolonged exposure to flux fumes, and I have already taken precautions to avoid it.

I was all excited and ready to start soldering, when I saw this on the flux box:

[image]

I'm OK with not putting that into my eyes and not tossing it into the waters, but why does it say **"CAUSES SEVERE SKIN BURNS"**?

All the dudes on YouTube that I saw soldering touched rosin with their bare hands.

While that doesn't necessarily means it is a safe practice, it surely didn't cause **severe** skin burns! I would rate something as severely burning if it burns like sulfuric acid, for example.

The only explanation I came up with was that maybe this product is made of really cheap dangerous stuff instead of rosin.

The product is this:

[image]

However, looking online I saw the same warnings even on boxes clearly marked as containing rosin flux.

If all those people on YouTube can handle this stuff barehanded, I'm clearly overreacting.

So I ask you, why is this stuff depicted as extremely dangerous on the box?

- Can I safely touch it?
- Are those warnings put on the box only for legal reasons?
- Are rosin based and different fluxes more or less dangerous?

Comment: You haven't bought rosin (*Kolophonium* in German) but *Lötfett*. The latter is meant for plumbing. Kolophonium will do nothing to the amount of oxides on old copper pipes, so you can't use it for that.

Comment: They do have a MSDS in German: https://www.wentronic.com/media/perfion/perfion-product/45238_MSDS.pdf

Comment: I think that you are overreacting. All the skin burns that I've had (and I had some in 30+ years as hobbyst) occurred when I mistakenly **touched the hot solder iron**. I've never had any occurrence of chemical burning from flux. This is not "extremely dangerous". Try to use it normally, as the Youtube folks did; and keep some tissue paper near you; but if you feel some skin rash, stitch, heating, stop immediately and clean your hands. EDIT: Please note that I'm talking about **rosin**, as I'm not German and I'm not aware of difference of _"Löftett"_ and _"Kolophonium"_, as @Janka explained.

Comment: @Janka Thank you, I was really confused by the Amazon reviews. A lot of people said that the title was wrong and the product was in truth soldering fluxant. However I later bought SRA rosin fluxant just to be sure.

Comment: @mguima I am overreacting without any doubt, however why use such a scary warning? I thought that even if not super dangerous there could be some truth in it.

Comment: Fumes may hart. At least use some fan move fumes from your face, not inhale that. Rosin is natural stuff, derived from pine sap.

Comment: @user263983 Yes thanks. I already setup a blowing fan and I'm furthermore using a P3 mask for that. I know it is overkill for such an hobbyist task, but better safe than sorry :)

Comment: @mars, your question makes me think in an answer that is more philosophical than practical. I think that the fact that some consummers blame vendors for every kind of failure has made vendors to overreact, until the point that the packages have labels advising about very unprobable risks. _Maybe_ this rosin can be absorbed by skin, and _maybe_ it could cause a little harm... But, just to be safe, just to be able to say "the consumer was warned about this, the vendors put those things in the labels...

Comment: @user263983:  Just being "natural" doesn't make it harmless.  Aconite and bella donna are natural, but you don't want to be fooling around with either one.  Maybe you'd like some hemlock tea - natural to be sure, and it'll kill you stone cold dead.

Comment: @mguima Yeah you are probably right. And honestly, that was exactly what I hoped to hear. Furthermore, I don't plan to take a bath in rosin, during normal use I suppose one barely even touches the flux with his hands.. Thank you.

Comment: @JRE You are right, but I suppose he simply meant that in this specific case, being derived from pine sap, it should not contain something too dangerous at least to the touch.

Comment: @mars:  What do you plan to do with the flux?  As a beginner, you should be  using a rosin core tin/lead solder.  You shouldn't need extra flux, and smearing some on your circuit board will just make a mess.  Buy a [roll of good solder like this stuff.](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Stannol-535768-Solder-Wire-Lead-Free/dp/B00O6Y9IKE/ref=mp_s_a_1_11?dchild=1&keywords=stannol+l%C3%B6tzinn+0%2C5+mm&qid=1606134886&sr=8-11)  If you are soldering wires or through hole parts on a printed circuit board, you should have no need for extra flux.

Comment: @JRE I indeed bought a rosin core wire. The extra flux should be needed for (correct me if I'm wrong) desoldering with the desolder wick. I don't plan to use it while actually soldering.

Comment: Solder wick contains flux.  It probably won't do what you expect, though.  Solder wick is for cleaning up stuff on the surface, not for removing solder from holes or removing parts from a board.  You use wick if you've got solder bridging two points on the board (two closely spaced pins) or where you have too much solder on one pin.

Comment: @JRE Yes, I have to solder wires to PCB pins, my understand is that if I mess up and, for example, solder by mistake two pins togheter, I use the wick to remove the solder in excess and remove the connection.

Comment: Rosin is pretty harmless stuff. Violinists have been putting it on their bows, and ballet dancers on their shoes, for hundreds of years. It is even used as an ingredient in chewing gum. But the flux paste used for soldering *plumbing* is completely different, and not harmless!

Comment: @mars: one thing to keep in mind, when reading SDS sheets, is to understand the audience of those SDS sheets. Typically, they are written in the context of a industrial factory situation where someone is handling the stuff all-day, every day. That's not to say not to take them seriously, but you need to read the details to see what the appropriate level of precaution is. Read the SDS for rubbing alcohol or motor fuel, totally appropriate for a factory with large amounts, totally unnecessary if you're fueling up your car.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be a translation issue, and it's a good job you asked the question; this is not the roisin flux commonly used in electronics, but Zinc Chloride (if my machine translation of the German datasheet is correct).

Zinc chloride is mildly corrosive - indeed, that's partly how it works, it's intended for soldering bulk copper in plumbing where removing the copper oxide layer is important.

I wouldn't panic about it but it's in the same category as kitchen cleaning chemicals where mere contact will sting a bit and you should wash it off promptly.

(Labelling it as "soldering paste" is even more confusing in English, because "solder paste" normally refers to tin or tin-lead particles in suspension used for automated soldering in ovens)

Comment: *Lötfett* is the correct term in German. The English term is wrong, yes.

Comment: Thank you. I already bought a box of SRA rosin fluxant, as this clearly is the wrong product. If I can safely touch this, I would suppose touching rosing is even safer, despite what the packaging may warn me about?

Comment: Soldering compounds for plumbing may work great for soldering electronics that only need to last a few minutes, but they will cause quickly essentially irreparable damage to the components and boards with which they are used.

Comment: The English name is not really confusing, because it is much more widely used in plumbing than in electronics. You are not likely to find automatic soldering oven consumables for sale in your local hardware store.